# Expensive computation time with finding ratios by ID index using Pandas and Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-processing

I am currently working on making a table that contains the ratios of pairs, applied with sort of minmaxscalar logic. However, I've suffered a very long and expensive time complexity with my code; one of the big reasons is the size of data. However, I am looking for more efficient code to do the same.

Here is the code that I've written and will explain what I do in the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

indexColumn = 'id'
limit_ratio = 0.6

result_data = pd.DataFrame([['id1', 1], ['id2', 1], ['id3', 1], ['id1', 2], ['id3', 2], ['id1', 4], ['id2', 4], ['id1', 5], ['id2', 5], ['id1', 6], ['id5', 6], ['id5', 7], ['id6', 7]], columns=['id', 'labels'])

result_data = result_data.groupby('labels')[indexColumn].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 2))).reset_index()
result_data = result_data.explode(indexColumn)
result_data = result_data.groupby(indexColumn)['labels'].agg('count').rename('count').reset_index()

result_data[['id1', 'id2']] = pd.DataFrame(result_data[indexColumn].tolist(),index=result_data.index)
```

At this point, `result_data` looks like

| id | count | id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (id1,id2) | 3 | id1 | id2 |
| (id1,id3) | 2 | id1 | id3 |
| (id1,id5) | 1 | id1 | id5 |
| (id2,id3) | 1 | id2 | id3 |
| (id5,id6) | 1 | id5 | id6 |

Basically, the code above counts the number of same labels that a pair has.
For example, `id1` and `id2` has label 1 data. Then, the count will increment by 1.
(I especially want to thank Joseph Fernandez, who helped me with the above code in the past)

```
result_data['ratio'] = result_data['count'] / float(result_data['count'].max())
result_data = result_data.sort_values(by='ratio', ascending=False)
```

Then, the `result_data` is

| id | count | id1 | id2 | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (id1,id2) | 3 | id1 | id2 | 1.000 |
| (id1,id3) | 2 | id1 | id3 | 0.667 |
| (id1,id5) | 1 | id1 | id5 | 0.333 |
| (id2,id3) | 1 | id2 | id3 | 0.333 |
| (id5,id6) | 1 | id5 | id6 | 0.333 |

For the `ratio` here, I calculate

1. (id1, id2) = 3 / max(count) = 3 / 3 = 1
2. (id1, id3) = 2 / max(count) = 2 / 3 = 0.667
3. (id1, id5) = 1 / max(count) = 1 / 3 = 0.333

This is a simple version of data to explain the code, but I am actually having the `result_data` which has 120 million number of rows, at this point. The following code is the problem that I have with exponential computation time because of its size.

```
if limit_ratio is not None:
    result_data[['ratio1', 'ratio2']] = np.NaN
    idlist = np.unique(result_data[['id1', 'id2']])
    for id in idlist:
        tmp = result_data[(result_data['id1'] == id) | (result_data['id2'] == id)][['id1', 'id2', 'count', 'ratio']]
        tmp['ratio1'] = tmp['count'] / float(tmp['count'].max())
        tmp['ratio2'] = tmp['ratio1']
        tmp.loc[tmp['id1'] == id, ['ratio2']] = np.NaN
        tmp.loc[tmp['id2'] == id, ['ratio1']] = np.NaN
        tmp = tmp[['id1', 'id2', 'ratio1', 'ratio2']]
        result_data = pd.merge(result_data, tmp, how='outer', on=['id1', 'id2'])
        result_data['ratio1'] = result_data['ratio1_x'].where(result_data['ratio1_x'].notna(), result_data['ratio1_y'])
        result_data['ratio2'] = result_data['ratio2_x'].where(result_data['ratio2_x'].notna(), result_data['ratio2_y'])
        result_data = result_data[['id1', 'id2', 'count', 'ratio', 'ratio1', 'ratio2']]
```

Then, the result will be

| id1 | id2 | count | ratio | ratio1 | ratio2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | id2 | 3 | 1.000 | 1.000 | 1.0 |
| id1 | id3 | 2 | 0.667 | 0.667 | 1.0 |
| id1 | id5 | 1 | 0.333 | 0.333 | 1.0 |
| id2 | id3 | 1 | 0.333 | 0.333 | 0.5 |
| id5 | id6 | 1 | 0.333 | 1.000 | 1.0 |

To explain more about ratio1 and ratio2,

`ratio1` is calculated by

1. (id1,id2) count / max(id1_count) = 3/3 = 1
2. (id1,id3) count / max(id1_count) = 2/3 = 0.667
3. (id1,id5) count / max(id1_count) = 1/3 = 0.333
4. (id2,id3) count / max(id2_count) = 1/3 = 0.333
5. (id5,id6) count / max(id5_count) = 1/1 = 1

`ratio2` is calculated by

1. (id1,id2) count / max(id2_count) = 3/3 = 1
2. (id1,id3) count / max(id3_count) = 2/2 = 1
3. (id1,id5) count / max(id5_count) = 1/1 = 1
4. (id2,id3) count / max(id3_count) = 1/2 = 0.5
5. (id5,id6) count / max(id6_count) = 1/1 = 1

After all, our final goal is to filter out rows with a `threshold`.

```
result_data = result_data[(result_data['ratio1'] >= float(limit_ratio)) | (result_data['ratio2'] >= float(limit_ratio))]
```

This will give me

| id1 | id2 | count | ratio | ratio1 | ratio2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | id2 | 3 | 1.000 | 1.000 | 1.0 |
| id1 | id3 | 2 | 0.667 | 0.667 | 1.0 |
| id1 | id5 | 1 | 0.333 | 0.333 | 1.0 |
| id5 | id6 | 1 | 0.333 | 1.000 | 1.0 |

Here, the code takes 12 minutes for each loop. The data has 50,000 unique IDs, expecting that 12 * 50000 = 60,000 minutes = 10,000 hours in calculation. For your information, I am currently using python 3.8.8, pandas == 1.2.3, and numpy == 1.19.5.

Comment: Can you please explain how'd you calculate `max(id1_count) ` or `max(id2_count) `?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Using the first row of the example above, I've got first id as id1 and second id as id2. Then, I calculate max(first id_count). The first_id counts are the ones that first id, id1, belongs to. More specific, id1 is in 1,2, and 3rd row of the example, equivalent to 3,2,1. Therefore, the max is 3.

Comment: I believe that there's a parenthesis missin in the line `result_data = result_data.groupby(indexColumn['labels'].agg('count').rename('count').reset_index()
`

Comment: @gofvonx Thank you for pointing it out. I've edited it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
>>> result_data

           id  count  id1  id2     ratio
0  (id1, id2)      3  id1  id2  1.000000
1  (id1, id3)      2  id1  id3  0.666667
2  (id1, id5)      1  id1  id5  0.333333
3  (id2, id3)      1  id2  id3  0.333333
4  (id5, id6)      1  id5  id6  0.333333
```

#### Solution

```
melted = result_data.melt('count', ['id1', 'id2'])
maxima = melted.groupby('value')['count'].max()

result_data['ratio1'] = result_data['count'] / result_data['id1'].map(maxima)
result_data['ratio2'] = result_data['count'] / result_data['id2'].map(maxima)

result_data = result_data.query("ratio1 >= @limit_ratio or ratio2 >= @limit_ratio")
```

#### Explanations

[`Melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe by specifying `id_vars` as `count` and `value_vars` as `id1, id2`

```
>>> melted

   count variable value
0      3      id1   id1
1      2      id1   id1
2      1      id1   id1
3      1      id1   id2
4      1      id1   id5
5      3      id2   id2
6      2      id2   id3
7      1      id2   id5
8      1      id2   id3
9      1      id2   id6
```

Now `group` the `melted` dataframe by `value` column and aggregate `count` using `max` to calculate `maximum` count value per `id`

```
>>> maxima

value
id1    3
id2    3
id3    2
id5    1
id6    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the calculated `maxima` on the columns `id1` and `id2`

```
>>> result_data['id1'].map(maxima)

0    3
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    1
Name: id1, dtype: int64

>>> result_data['id1'].map(maxima)

0    3
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    1
Name: id2, dtype: int64
```

Now divide the `count` column with the above mapped `id1` and `id2` columns respectively to calculate `ratio1` and `ratio2`

```
>>> result_data[['ratio1', 'ratio2']]

     ratio1  ratio2
0  1.000000     1.0
1  0.666667     1.0
2  0.333333     1.0
3  0.333333     0.5
4  1.000000     1.0
```

[`Query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) the dataframe to filter out the rows based on the given `threshold` value in `limit_ratio`

```
>>> result_data

           id  count  id1  id2     ratio    ratio1  ratio2
0  (id1, id2)      3  id1  id2  1.000000  1.000000     1.0
1  (id1, id3)      2  id1  id3  0.666667  0.666667     1.0
2  (id1, id5)      1  id1  id5  0.333333  0.333333     1.0
4  (id5, id6)      1  id5  id6  0.333333  1.000000     1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try it right away.

Comment: @tkinter Glad i could help.